# Google sheets copying data from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets

I'm pretty sure this is an easy fix but I currently have a google sheet set up with multiple tabs, lets say we have debits, credits and balance.
When you add a new client to credits it will automatically add the appropriate fields to debits and balance and total. But I currently have it set up relating to the cell, so the balance cell on that tab is `SUM(Credit!E4:Z4)-SUM(Debit!E4:X4)` the Name Cell on that sheet is: `=concatenate(Credit!B4," ",Credit!C4)` The Debit sheet is set up with `=Credit!B4, =Credit!C4 =Credit!D4` etc.
Its related to the cell, so if I try to sort the cells by, lets say something useful like alpha lastname, it screws up everything. I just cant remember what I need to do to fix it. Is it an arrayformula? I just cant remember how to do this, or what words I need to google to figure it out.

Comment: Hi there @user11649927 ! After reviewing your question I don't have a clear idea of the scenario. Could you please share an example file of your current Sheet? To better help you, please share too your desired final file.

Comment: It sounds like you are possibly sorting only part of your data, which gets things out of alignment.  If you share a sample copy of your sheet, using the following guide, with the minimal amount of data needed to demonstrate the issue, and hand enter your desired result, we should be able to help you.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en